# Why aren't my tests running in the expected order?

Tags: c#, nunit, playwright

I have 1 test that runs significantly longer than others so I want that to start running first so others can be run in parallel with it.

The test in the derived class is using Order(1), as is the TestFixture attribute of the class. My understanding is that this class should now be run first, with this test being selected first from within this class.

Unfortunately, the tests are still being run in their default order. Any ideas as to why?!?!

```
using GembaCloud.PlaywrightTests.Pages;

namespace GembaCloud.PlaywrightTests.TestClasses
{
    [TestFixture, Order(1)]
    public class UserAuthenticationTests : BaseTests
    {
        [Test, Timeout(1200000), Order(1)]
        public async Task user_is_prevented_from_logging_in_for_15_minutes_after_5_failed_attempts()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Here is the offending test class: https://github.com/Keiggo/GembaCloud/blob/master/TestClasses/UserAuthenticationTests.cs

Comment: Note that the `Order` attribute on a TextFixture makes this run before any other fixtures **in the same namespace**. Do you have tests in other namespaces?

Comment: Great question. I shall double-check that tomorrow but they should all be in the same namespace

Comment: No dice. The base class, this test class, and all other test classes are in the namespace GembaCloud.PlaywrightTests.TestClasses. Thanks anyway :(

Answer (score 1):

From the [Nunit docs](https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/writing-tests/attributes/order.html):

> As stated, ordering is local to the test that contains the ordered
> tests. For test cases (methods) ordering applies within the containing
> fixture.
> **For fixtures it applies within the containing namespace**.
> There is no facility in NUnit to order tests globally.

So to run the unit tests in the expected order, put them all in the same namespace.

Also, make sure that all your tests and test fixtures have the correct order.

Additionally, please note that **tests do not wait for previous tests to complete**. If multiple threads are used, **the test can be run while some previous tests are running**.

If the problem still exists, could you please share a repository link to investigate this problem using the source code?

Comment: As best I can tell: all test classes are in the same namespace, there is only 1 test that should be marked to run first (the rest should run in the default order). The test does not run as part of the first batch of tests to be run. This is the offending test class: https://github.com/Keiggo/GembaCloud/blob/master/TestClasses/UserAuthenticationTests.cs

Comment: I've tried to reproduce the issue, but in my case the tests are executing in the expecting order. Could you please specify how you check their run order? For example, you could add some console output for the tests to see the thread ID and time to call: `Console.WriteLine($"Test A: Thread ID: {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}, Time: {DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss.fff tt")}");`.

Comment: I'm running the tests locally and just seeing which ones are spinning up in the test runner first. I will add some logging to the setup step and see where that gets me

Comment: There's something funky going on with the `ParallelScope`. What seems to be happening here is that first it will run tests that are alphabetically first, THEN it will run tests that have `ParallelScope.Self`, honouring the `Order()` of those tests.. I'm not 100% sure if that's correct but it sure seems to be. Is anything in there making any sense???

Comment: What is the NUnit version?

Comment: There's an interesting mismatch of numbers here. Not sure if normal..? ``<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Playwright.NUnit" Version="1.37.1" />`` ``<PackageReference Include="NUnit" Version="3.13.3" />``  ``<PackageReference Include="NUnit3TestAdapter" Version="4.5.0" />``  ``<PackageReference Include="NUnit.Analyzers" Version="3.6.1" />``

Comment: The dependencies seem to be fine. How do you actually run the tests? Using the Visual Studio? Any CI/CD runner? Try disabling all tests, but keep a couple of ordered tests to check behaviour.

Comment: Visual Studio and also as a task in our Azure release pipeline. There is only the one ordered test as it's the only long-running one. Does that change anything?